# Count in Excel over a range using 2 columns of data

Tags: excel, countif

Tried looking for an answer first...

I want to count the number of items that were open between 1-7 days, 8-14 days, etc etc (open and closed on same day = open for 1 day)

Is there a way I can count this directly using the 2 columns holding the data **without** creating a 3rd column for `Date Closed - Date Opened +1`??

So in this example, what can I use to calculate that the number of 1-7 days items is 2? (Items 1 and 3)

`Item #  Open    Closed`

`1  01/06/2014  01/06/2014`

`2  05/05/2014  20/06/2014`

`3  10/06/2014  16/06/2014`

`4  08/06/2014  15/06/2014`

`5  02/06/2014  19/06/2014`

Many thanks :o)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the versatile `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(C2:C6-B2:B6+1>7))
```

assuming your start date column is `B` and end date column is `C`. The second part of the formula will determine all date spans which are larger than 7, and the `1*` will convert the `TRUE` values to 1 in order to sum them up.

Comment: Thanks but I want a count, not a sum? Apologies if I'm missing something? In words I want 'Count where Col C minus Col B is less than or equal to 7'

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to make it avoid empty rows? Thanks again.

Comment: It should evaluate empty rows to 1, and thus the condition is false and the row not counted.